# solution without using the L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to complete the solution without using the L'Hopital. I got here

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log \left(x^{4}+1\right)+1}{\log \left(x^{3}+2\right)-3}$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\log \left(x^{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)\right)+1}{\log \left(x^{3}\left(1+\frac{2}{x^{3}}\right)\right)-3}\right)$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\log \left(x^{4}\right)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)+1}{\log \left(x^{3}\right)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)-3}\right)$

Comment: You are on the right track. Now note that $\log (1 + 1/x^n)$ converges to $0$, so you can erase it, and you just need to compute $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log x^4 + 1}{\log x^3 -3}$$ Recall that $\log x^n = n \log x$. Can you conclude now?

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: Posting this as a comment, rather than an answer because of the informality.  Once you realize that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log(x) = \infty$, the problem can be immediately solved (informally) **without math**.  It becomes immediate that the numerator's (+1) term and the denominator's (-3) term can be ignored.  Further, for any **fixed** $k$ and any $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, as $x\to\infty$, $~(x^n + k)$ will (informally) *go* to $x^n$.  Therefore, very informally, the problem immediately reduces to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4\log(x)}{3\log(x)}.$  ...see next comment

Comment: I'm not saying that this analysis qualifies as an answer that a teacher will accept.  However, I am saying that if your work were to produce any *other* answer besides $\frac{4}{3}$, then you would **know** that you have made an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your are almost done :

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\log \left(x^{4}\right)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)+1}{\log \left(x^{3}\right)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)-3}\right)$

$= \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{4log(x)}{3log(x)}$

$=\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: You should probably explain the steps behind how you got from your first equation to second one.